# How can I prevent Google Apps Scripts from returning HTML to slack after processing a custom slash command?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slack-api

I am using a custom slash command in Slack to add data to a Google Doc via Google Apps Scripts, however, when the script finishes running (successfully), Google Script sends this to Slack, which users will interpret as an error:

```
<DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico"><title>Error</title><style type="text/css">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}</style></head><body><div><img src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png"></div><center>The script completed but did not return anything.</center></body></html>
```

How can I prevent this message from being sent to Slack?

```
function doPost(request) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id-would-go-here');
  var params = request.parameters;

  var nR = getNextRow(sheets) + 1;

  if (params.token == "token-would-go-here") {

    // FALL BACK TO DEFAULT TEXT IF NO ORDER PROVIDED
    var order   = params.text || "No Order Entered";
    var employee = params.user_name || "Name Error";

    // RECORD TIMESTAMP AND USER NAME IN SPREADSHEET
    sheets.getRangeByName('date').getCell(nR,1).setValue(new Date());
    sheets.getRangeByName('employee').getCell(nR,1).setValue(employee);

    // RECORD UPDATE INFORMATION INTO SPREADSHEET
    sheets.getRangeByName('order').getCell(nR,1).setValue(order);

    var channel = "lunch-orders";

    postResponse(channel,order,employee);

    var eph_url = params.response_url; 
    var eph_response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(eph_url,200);

  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function postResponse(channel, order, employee) {

  var payload = {
    "channel": "#lunch-orders",
    "username": "Lunch Order",
    "link_names": 1,
    "attachments":[
       {
          "fallback": "A lunch order was placed, but the display here is a little messed up. Check the Google Doc to view the order.",
          "mrkdwn_in": ["pretext"],
          "color": "good",
          "fields":[
             {
                "title":"" + employee + "'s Lunch Order",
                "value": "" + order + "",
                "short":false
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
  };

  var url = 'incoming-webhook-url-goes-here';
  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your setup is a little off. You don't POST the data back, you return it using ContentService. Now a small issue is that you have to run the webapp as anonymous authentication.  What I do is save the slack token in the script property services and make sure the requesting Slack app's token matches.

Here is an example webhook that simply writes the parameters passed to the switch command to a spreadsheet.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var returnMessage;
  var slackToken = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("SlackToken") ;
  var postData = parseParams(e.postData.getDataAsString());
  if(postData.token === slackToken){
    SpreadsheetApp.openById('.....').getSheetByName("Log").appendRow([postData]);
    returnMessage = "Your record has been logged."
  }else{
     returnMessage = "Invalid Token"
  }

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({text:returnMessage})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

function parseParams(postData){
  var postObj = {}
   postData.split("&").map(function(param){var thisParam = param.split("="); postObj[thisParam[0]] = thisParam[1]});
   return postObj;
}
```